# Java make POST request to express js server and download PDF file

Tags: java, express

I have express js server as API. I need to send POST request to that server and my website needs to download PDF file to the client computer.

Here is my express server code:

```
const pdf = await generatePDF(data.originURL, data.url, data.pageOrientation); //pdf generation

// send pdf to client
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
  'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=file.pdf',
  'Content-Length': pdf.length
});
res.end(pdf);
```

In my website I have commandButton which call the action for POST request;
What I'm a doing wrong, I'm not getting any downloaded file in my website?

Method for making POST request:

```
public void makeRequest() {
  HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        String imageExportServer = "url....";
        URL url = new URL(imageExportServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();


            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
            try {

                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                try (OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream()) {

                        JsonObject configJson = new JsonObject();
                        configJson.addProperty("originURL", "url");
                        configJson.addProperty("url", "url...");
                        configJson.addProperty("pageOrientation", "someText");
                        stream.write(Builder().create().toJson(configJson).getBytes());

                }

                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode != 200) {
                    //log.warn("Error response: ", responseCode);


                }


                    String fileName = "";
                    String disposition = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
                    String contentType = connection.getContentType();
                    int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();

                    System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
                    System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
                    System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
                    System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

                    // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                    // opens an output stream to save into file
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("neki.pdf");

                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                    outputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("neki.pdf");
                    fos.write(buffer);
                    fos.close();

                    System.out.println("File downloaded");


                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
            } finally {
                //log.info("Exporting chart of type '%s' took %sms.", "tyoe", stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        //log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And why do you think this is JSF related? And both java and javascript  at the same time (it's like stating it is java and .Net or Windows and Linux at the same time... Or German and Spanish

Comment: Becouse my website respond with no downloaded file. 

Express -> my server
JSF -> my website
Javascript -> server code

Comment: But does your webserver explode? Or just die? Or start laughing?